# Block numbers and limit edit text in android

Tags: android

I have a question about limit number in editText. I want to user can write only number from 1-30. When user want to put 32 I want to block this possibility. I want to check if user put first first number 4 I wnat to block putting more numbers. When put first number 3 I want to block all nubmers except 0. How can I do that? I use textWatcher to watch text but how can I block keyboard?

Comment: Why don't you use `NumberPickers` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            int num = 0;
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString()+source.toString());
                if (!(num > 0 && num <= 30)) {
                    return "";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    editListenPort.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: this is good but I have a problem, because when I put number 6 filter check this, but when I put first nubmer 5 and after nubmer 8 filter check first number 5 and after that check nubmer 8, but in edittext I have number 58. How can I check in filter all text from edit text, not only one by one

Comment: I solve the problem please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I kind of did the same thing:

```
editListenPort.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    /** Not implemented */
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
    /** Not implemented */
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    /** After text has been entered into the EditText, this updates the TextView 
     * next to it with the new value. A sanity check is performed if there is no 
     * text entered at all, upon which the listen port is set to 0. */
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int numberOfChars = s.length();
        if(numberOfChars > 0){
            mOwnPort = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
        } else if(numberOfChars <= 0){
            mOwnPort = 0;
        }
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelOwnIpData)).setText("Own IP-endpoint:\n" + mOwnIp + ":" + mOwnPort);
    }
});
```

With this piece of code, I check the input of an EditText and update a TextView that's located directly next to the EditText.

Though I don't think it's a problem if you upate the EditText itself or give a warning.